# I keep getting a 404 error when I try to add a background image to a div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I am trying to create a div as I press enter in my search bar. That part works for me and if I keep pressing enter a new div is created. However, I cannot give the created div a background image. My console keeps giving me a 404 error. Here is my code:

```
function appendToDom(poster) {
    var aPoster = $('<div>');
    aPoster.css({
        display: 'inline block',
        float: 'left',
        margin: '10px',
        marginLeft: '37px',
        marginTop: '20px',
        width: '200px',
        height: '300px',
        fontSize: '36px',
        color: 'black'
        //backgroundImage: '../services/images/1425663956-outline.png'
    })
    $(aPoster).css("background-image", "url(~/desktop/MyMovies/public/js/images/1425663956-outline.png)");
    $(main).append(aPoster);
```

I tried to put my images file in a bunch of places and I changed the path a bunch of times. My ultimate goal is to add the image provided by the api I'm using as the background image of each div and have the image I am currently trying to use as the default for when the api has no image for a given data point.

I am working in node if that helps.

Comment: If you are getting a 404 that indicates that your path to the image is incorrect, not that your code is wrong. I suspect that your issue is that you are using a tilde(~) vs a absolute path. Try navigating to the image in your browser first, then take that path and paste it in your code. If this is just local, the images should resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier/better to use relative directories. Similar to how you have in your commented out section of your example.  In my opinion, files or assets that the program will use should be somewhere inside your project folder anyway.

Try `url(./../images/question.png)`depending on your file system.

Comment: I got the image now, but it won't show up. here is my code:

Comment: function appendToDom(poster) {
        var aPoster = $('<div>');
        aPoster.css({
         display: 'inline block',
         float: 'left',
         margin: '10px',
         marginLeft: '37px',
         marginTop: '20px',
         width: '200px',
         height: '300px',
         fontSize: '36px',
         color: 'black',
         backgroundColor: 'white',
         backgroundSize: '200px 300px',
         backgroundImage: './../images/question.png'
        })$(main).append(aPoster);
    }

Comment: I edited my answer to be more tailored to you. I would try wrapping it in url(...) and also, backgroundColor may be conflicting with the stuff. I would comment that out for tesitng

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
$(aPoster).attr("style","background-image: url(~/desktop/MyMovies/public/js/images/1425663956-outline.png)");
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't understand the `~` in the file path `~/desktop/MyMovies/public/js/images/1425663956-outline.png`. It only has meaning in a shell with access to your local filesystem. You need to use the URL where that image file is being served.

Comment: What if that image is not from the web and its on my computer in my MyMovies directory?